# bestway to parse xml services in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript.I wanted to parse xml and displayed in javascript.I used the following code.it did not give output?any help please? what is advantage if we use jQuery  and difference between normal javascript and jQuery?`

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $.get("http://www.hindu.com/rss/01hdline.xml", function(response){
     var response = $.paseXML(response);
      var $xml = $(response);

   //Now you can find any xml node with $xml using various methods of jQuery
  //E.g
   alert($xml.find( "title" ));   
  });
  });
```

Comment: shouldn't `$.paseXML` be `$.parseXML` ?

Comment: i tried , it return "object",not node value?---- alert($xml.find( "title" ));

Answer (score 0):

If you used `jQuery` you dont have to write all the code which you have written, `jQuery` will do it for you and it works across all the browsers. Also it has built in utility to parse xml using which you can easily traverse through the xml document and write you logic. Try this

```
$.get("http://www.hindu.com/rss/01hdline.xml", function(response){
   var response = $.paseXML(response);
   var $xml = $(response);

   //Now you can find any xml node with $xml using various methods of jQuery
   //E.g
   alert($xml.find( "title" ));   
});
```

The reason your code is not working because

You cannot do cross-domain XMLHttpRequests.

You might instead consider either XMLHttp-request your own server to fetch the remote XML content for you (php script, for example)

Comment: you did not say the reason why the code  i mentioned is not working?

Comment: which plugin i have to download to run your code?I see  lot of plugins  such as "jqtouch.js" , "jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js".which one I have to use,please

Comment: I have changed my code as u told,But still now i cant get alert..see my question again